# Delete duplicates within groups?

Tags: r

Code for example data:

```
    mydf<-data.frame(Group_ID=c("337", "337", "201", "201", "470", "470", "999", "999"), 
             Timestamp=c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), 
             MU=c("1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Example dataframe:

```
  Group_ID Timestamp MU
1      337         A  1
2      337         A  1
3      201         B  2
4      201         B  3
5      470         C  4
6      470         D  4
7      999         E  5
8      999         F  6
```

Within "Group_ID", I want to retain only entries where neither "Timestamp" nor "MU" is duplicated. Thus, in this example, **only rows 7 & 8 would be retained** ("Group_ID" 999 has unique entries for both "Timestamp" and "MU").

Some of my attempts:

```
mydf<-mydf %>%
  group_by(Group_ID) %>%
  filter(unique(Timestamp))
```

Returns error:

> "Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector"

If this did work, I'd then run it again using `unique(MU)`

```
mydf<-mydf %>%
  group_by(Group_ID) %>%
  mydf[!duplicated(mydf$Timestamp, fromLast = TRUE),]
```

Returns error:

> "Length of logical index vector must be 1 or 3 (the number of columns), not 8"

(Again, I'd run the code again using MU)

I've looked through similar questions but haven't found one with the same scenario. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we are using `filter`, it expects a logical vector.  The output of `unique` is just unique elemnents of that column (`character` class).  So it is not going to work.  We can use `duplicated` to get a logical vector of duplicate elements, negate (`!`). so that the TRUE -> FALSE and viceversa to get only the first non-duplicate element

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% 
   group_by(Group_ID) %>% 
   filter(!(duplicated(Timestamp, fromLast = TRUE)| duplicated(Timestamp)))
```

---

Or group by both 'Group_ID', 'Timestamp' and `filter` based on the number of rows

```
mydf %>%
   group_by(Group_ID, Timestamp) %>%
   filter(n() == 1)
```

If we need only the '999' 'Group_ID'

```
mydf %>% 
  group_by(Group_ID) %>%
  filter_at(vars(Timestamp,  MU),  all_vars(n_distinct(.) == n()))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   Group_ID [1]
#  Group_ID Timestamp MU   
#  <fct>    <fct>     <fct>
#1 999      E         5    
#2 999      F         6
```

---

Or use `distinct` directly

```
distinct(mydf, Group_ID, Timestamp, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Comment: Could there be a `base` possibility to achieve this?

Comment: @NelsonGon Just use`duplicated` on the columns of interest 'GroupID', 'Timestamp'.  Not clear about the expected output though

Comment: Yes but if the columns are very many, how can one aggregate by group(s)?

Comment: @akrun Thank you. Your solutions return the first entry within a group with duplicated Timestamps. Could it be altered so it excludes all rows where Timestamp is duplicated? (so only Group_IDs 470 and 999 would remain)?

Comment: @Emily Do you need `mydf %>% group_by(Group_ID) %>% filter(!(duplicated(Timestamp, fromLast = TRUE)| duplicated(Timestamp)))`

Comment: @NelsonGon Something like `mydf[!(duplicated(mydf[1:2])|duplicated(mydf[1:2], fromLast = TRUE)),]`

Comment: @Emily I am a. bit confused now.  your description says rows 7 and 8, but now you want to have 470 and 999 IDs, which one is correct?

Comment: @akrun Sorry. 470 and 999 is correct only working with "Timestamp". Once I add in "MU" using that same command, only two entries for 999 will remain

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = function(x, f){
    ave(as.numeric(as.factor(x)),
        f,
        FUN = function(y) length(unique(y)) == length(y))
}

inds = Reduce("&", lapply(mydf[c("Timestamp", "MU")],
                          function(x) foo(x, mydf$Group_ID) == 1))

mydf[inds,]
#  Group_ID Timestamp MU
#7      999         E  5
#8      999         F  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base solution :

```r
is.unique <- function(x) !(duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE))
mydf[is.unique(mydf[1:2]) & is.unique(mydf[c(1,3)]),]
#>   Group_ID Timestamp MU
#> 7      999         E  5
#> 8      999         F  6
```